# Editing the action strips in the NLA editor

Tags: nla-editor

Are the action strips in the NLA editor able to be actually edited, as you would edit clips in a NLE? I was hoping I could grab the end of one and drag to trim it, or say ctrl-drag the edge to stretch it, or even something like the slip tool in Premiere, where the in and out points of the source clip move, but the clip boundaries stay the same in the track. Is this possible?
All I can do is drag them in time, to change any of the other parameters I have to go into the side menu. To be clear, I want to be able to visually edit them without doing this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can stretch is with S.

You can trim it here: frame end

[image]

I don't know what the slip tool does, so would be nice if you could explain that in your question.

Comment: Well the quastion I'm asking is is it possible to visually edit clips in the NLA editor. Looks like it isn't which seems a shame.

Comment: yes, you are right, it's a bit complicated that way. But hopefully one day they will improve this.